# How can I install older versions of Adobe Flash on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium, adobe-flash

I've found [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html), but is it the correct way to install a Flash plugin for Chrome? I preferably want to try v11 or 12

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Please take a look: [How can I run the system plug-in, debugger or alternate versions of Flash Player in Google Chrome?](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html#How_can_I_run_debugger_or_alternate_versions_of_Flash_Player_in_Google_Chrome)